# how can I display the last messages of all users?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to display the last conversation (messages) between a user and other users along with the name and profile picture of the other user. Whatsapp and Messenger homepages are typical examples of what I want to achieve.

I have 2 tables: users and chat tables

**users table**

```
user_id     username      photo
    1        elexis        img
    2        rooney        img
    3        wayne         img
```

**chat table**

```
   id     user_id       friend_id       message         msg_time
    1        1             2             hello        21-08-19 04:00
    2        2             1             i'm good     21-08-19 04:00
    3        3             1             hey          21-08-19 04:00
```

The expected result for elexis should be:

```
 1   2    I'm good  **promise**  img    21-08-19 04:00
 1   3    hey       **wayne**    img    21-08-19 04:00
```

The expected result for promise should be:

```
 1   2    I'm good  **elexis**  img    21-08-19 04:00
```

However, what I am getting is:

```
1   2    hello  **promise**  img    21-08-19 04:00
2   1    hello  **elexis**   img    21-08-19 04:00
2   1    I'm good  **promise**  img    21-08-19 04:00
1   2    I'm good  **elexis**   img    21-08-19 04:00
3   1    hey       **wayne**    img    21-08-19 04:00
1   3    hey       **elexis**   img    21-08-19 04:00
```

My code is thus:

```sql
SELECT c.*, u.username, 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, friend_id,id, message 
  FROM chat 
  WHERE user_id = 1 OR friend_id = 1 
  UNION SELECT friend_id, user_id,id, message 
  FROM chat 
  WHERE friend_id = 2 OR user_id = 2 
  ORDER BY id DESC) c 
ON c.friend_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select c.*
from chat c
where 1 in (c.friend_id, c.user_id) and
      c.msg_time = (select max(c2.msg_time)
                    from chat c2
                    where (c.friend_id, c.user_id) in ( (c2.friend_id, c2.user_id), (c2.user_id, c2.friend_id) );
```